# Offscreen DIV not expanding with new HTML content (JQuery)

Tags: jquery, css, html, height

I have a situation where I'm using an offscreen DIV (top: -2000px) to test for the height of something so I can expand items on screen properly (using JQuery). It works perfect for form fields inside a single DIV, but the second I stack DIVS into a wrapping list I get 0px heights.

**Works**: (returns proper css('height');

```
<div id="sample-wrapper">
<div>all my content</div>
</div>
```

**Broken**: (return 0px css('height');

```
<div id="sample-wrapper">
<div class="listItem1">blah</div>
<div class="listItem2">blah</div>
</div>
```

What would be a good display / position / float / clear setting for my wrapper DIV tag to test height in multiple scenarios?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: I can't seem to find a problem: http://jsfiddle.net/b4zEx/

Comment: Thank you for putting that sample together. I've updated it a bit. The HTML content is loaded in via an ajax call, so I'm wondering if it's a latent .html() filler that's the problem. Let me update it further and try again.

Comment: sounds like you're calculating the height right after the ajax call rather than in the callback ?

Comment: Nope, using a callback. I've reworked the script (http://jsfiddle.net/DNhJV/10/) and now the button doesn't seem to work. I've recreated the essential method with all the exact wrapping css DIV elements. Granted, the version on fiddle did work further than my other version.

Comment: There was a small typo in your html string, and the page wrapper was on top of the button, so it couldn't be clicked. http://jsfiddle.net/DNhJV/14/

Comment: Is there a way for me to message you a link?

Comment: I don't know why, but just pressing Update seems to create errors from my end http://jsfiddle.net/DNhJV/21/

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/33428/discussion-between-dom-day-and-mark-lowe)